# How can I add the Assembly* values back to my executable?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, resources, windows-screensaver

As part of the solution to [How do I control the screensaver name shown in the drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218976),
I asked I have added a resource file to my project. I was able to set the icon for the application in the resource file but I'm not sure how the other attributes (ie: File Version, Description, Copyright, etc.) should be set. I imagine I need to put them in the resource file but I'm not clear on the details. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file version, description, etc, are stored in a [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx) resource.

See the [Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981(VS.85).aspx) topic at MSDN for more info.

Edit: yes, those are the fields that are stored in the VERSIONINFO resource.

Comment: Lol it's right there when I add a resource too. Any advice on automatically generating this from my AssemblyInfo.cs file like normally happens when you aren't including a Win32 resource?

Comment: @Cory: sorry no, I don't know if the magic mechanism call be called explicitly.  I can some example code of how to fill out a VERSIONINFO resource if you need it.